# PHP displaying as plaintext

Tags: php, .htaccess, plaintext

http://www.clare-ents.com/test/index.php

Using a new host...

I know it's something to do with .htaccess and I've got it in the root folder:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using short tags? `<? ?>` without the `<?php`? The server's PHP install has to be set up to use those or it will output plaintext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HEAD request to that URL says:

```
 Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php
```

This suggests that your webserver does support .htaccess configuration but does not have the PHP module loaded.

Consult your system administrator.

Comment: My system administrator has told me to enable PHP via CGI, and the help page says to add "AddHandler cgi-script .php
Options +ExecCGI", which is now returning a 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably missing PHP module loaded in your apache.